# Process ajax data to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I need to process some data from an ajax call and fill in a JSON object.
I have problem defining the correct loop.

I defined this variable

```js
var reportData = {
  "offerta": {
    "codice": offerta_corrente,
    "data": "",
    "oggetto": ""
  },
  "cliente": {
    "societa": "",
    "indirizzo": "",
    "cap": "",
    "citta": "",
    "provincia": ""
  },
  "sconti_totale": {
    "sconto1": sconto1,
    "sconto2": sconto2,
    "sconto3": sconto3
  },
  "zone": [],
};
```

then from an ajax call I got this data:

```js
[{
  "customer": [{
    "codcli": "CL0002",
    "societa": "ACME s.r.l",
    "indirizzo": "via S. Giovanni, 100",
    "citta": "",
    "provincia": "",
    "cap": "",
    "paese": ""
  }],
  "rows": [{
    "zona": "Area vendita",
    "codET": "PED-40-10102",
    "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
    "L": "100",
    "P": "100",
    "H": "25",
    "codfinET": "---",
    "descfinET": "grezzo",
    "umET": "NR",
    "qty": "2",
    "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
    "PrezzoTotale": "514.8",
    "Sconto1": "0",
    "Sconto2": "0",
    "Sconto3": "0"
  }, {
    "zona": "Area vendita",
    "codET": "PED-40-50000",
    "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
    "L": "100",
    "P": "100",
    "H": "25",
    "codfinET": "---",
    "descfinET": "grezzo",
    "umET": "NR",
    "qty": "2",
    "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
    "PrezzoTotale": "514.8",
    "Sconto1": "0",
    "Sconto2": "0",
    "Sconto3": "0"
  }, {
    "zona": "Area magazzino",
    "codET": "PED-40-10102",
    "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
    "L": "100",
    "P": "100",
    "H": "25",
    "codfinET": "---",
    "descfinET": "grezzo",
    "umET": "NR",
    "qty": "1",
    "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
    "PrezzoTotale": "257.4",
    "Sconto1": "0",
    "Sconto2": "0",
    "Sconto3": "0"
  }, {
    "zona": "Area vetrina",
    "codET": "PED-40-10102",
    "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
    "L": "100",
    "P": "100",
    "H": "25",
    "codfinET": "---",
    "descfinET": "grezzo",
    "umET": "NR",
    "qty": "1",
    "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
    "PrezzoTotale": "257.4",
    "Sconto1": "0",
    "Sconto2": "0",
    "Sconto3": "0"
  }]
}]
```

I extracted rows array with data[0].rows, but I was not able to build the loop to convert and build this final JSON object

```js
{
  "offerta": {
    "codice": "2017-00007",
    "data": "",
    "oggetto": ""
  },
  "cliente": {
    "societa": "ACME s.r.l",
    "indirizzo": "via S. Giovanni, 100",
    "cap": "",
    "citta": "",
    "provincia": ""
  },
  "sconti_totale": {
    "sconto1": "0.00",
    "sconto2": "0.00",
    "sconto3": "0.00"
  },
  "zone": [{
    "nome": "Area vendita",
    "items": [{
      "zona": "Area vendita",
      "codET": "PED-40-10102",
      "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
      "L": "100",
      "P": "100",
      "H": "25",
      "codfinET": "---",
      "descfinET": "grezzo",
      "umET": "NR",
      "qty": "2",
      "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
      "PrezzoTotale": "514.8",
      "Sconto1": "0",
      "Sconto2": "0",
      "Sconto3": "0"
    }, {
      "zona": "Area vendita",
      "codET": "PED-40-50000",
      "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
      "L": "100",
      "P": "100",
      "H": "25",
      "codfinET": "---",
      "descfinET": "grezzo",
      "umET": "NR",
      "qty": "2",
      "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
      "PrezzoTotale": "514.8",
      "Sconto1": "0",
      "Sconto2": "0",
      "Sconto3": "0"
    }]
  }, {
    "nome": "Area magazzino",
    "items": [{
      "zona": "Area magazzino",
      "codET": "PED-40-10102",
      "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
      "L": "100",
      "P": "100",
      "H": "25",
      "codfinET": "---",
      "descfinET": "grezzo",
      "umET": "NR",
      "qty": "1",
      "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
      "PrezzoTotale": "257.4",
      "Sconto1": "0",
      "Sconto2": "0",
      "Sconto3": "0"
    }]
  }, {
    "nome": "Area vetrina",
    "items": [{
      "zona": "Area vetrina",
      "codET": "PED-40-10102",
      "descET": "PEDANA ESP. CON PIANO IN LAMIERA ALL. MANDORLATO",
      "L": "100",
      "P": "100",
      "H": "25",
      "codfinET": "---",
      "descfinET": "grezzo",
      "umET": "NR",
      "qty": "1",
      "PrezzoSingolo": "257.4",
      "PrezzoTotale": "257.4",
      "Sconto1": "0",
      "Sconto2": "0",
      "Sconto3": "0"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I'm interested in the loop to fill the "zone" part of the JSON object.

This was the piece of code I was working on without any good result... please help me going on the right way.

```js
for (index = 0; index < data[0].rows.length; ++index) {
  if (data[0].rows[index].zona != currzona) {
    if (index > 0) {
      newzona.push(curr_items)
    };
    // aggiungo l'elemento zona
    var newzona = reportData.zone.push({
      "nome": data[0].rows[index].zona
    });
    // aggiungo il nodo dell'articolo
    var curr_items = new Array();
  }
  curr_items.push(data[0].rows[index]);
  currzona = data[0].rows[index].zona;
  console.log(currzona);
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as a "JSON object". There is JSON, which is simply a string in a particular format, and JavaScript objects. It would also be nice to show you actually tried something and did some research. For instance, there are many, many question regarding manipulating JavaScript objects and arrays. You'll want to be specific in what the requirements are for the transformation.

Comment: @Mike, I made a lot of reassearch but was not able to get the right resault.... I edited my original ppost including the piece of code I was working on

Comment: the question really doesn't seem to be about JSON, as you are seemingly working with plain ol' javascript objects in your code - so, what you're asking is, given the two inputs, how do you get the output the way you want